# Flutter : Add the same widget when pressed on floating button

Tags: flutter, dart

[image: I have the first container in this shape and i want to repeat it with the same width and height when i press on to floating button .]

[image: But i get this shape]

I have the first container in this shape and i want to repeat it with the same width and height when i press on to floating button But i get this shape .

the first picture contain the container which i want the second one contain the added container after pressed the button .
this is my code which i use to do that and the new container return with small height and same width i use it because if the user want to add more information

```
class Body extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _BodyState createState() => _BodyState();
}

class _BodyState extends State<Body> {
  int count = 1;
  List<TextEditingController> _nameController = [
    for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++) TextEditingController()
  ];

  List<TextEditingController> _phoneController = [
    for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++) TextEditingController()
  ];
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Expanded(
        child: Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.white,
      body: Container(
          alignment: Alignment.center,
          height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.37,
          width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.92,
          child: NotificationListener<OverscrollIndicatorNotification>(
              // ignore: missing_return
              onNotification: (OverscrollIndicatorNotification overscroll) {
                overscroll.disallowGlow();
              },
              child: PageView.builder(
                  reverse: false,
                  pageSnapping: false,
                  controller: PageController(viewportFraction: 1),
                  itemCount: count,
                  itemBuilder: (context, i) {
                    print(i);
                    if (i == 0) {
                      return Padding(
                          padding: EdgeInsets.only(
                              left: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.015,
                              top: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.08,
                              bottom:
                                  MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.015),
                          child: Material(
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(50.0),
                            color: Colors.white,
                            elevation: 4.0,
                            child: Container(
                              alignment: Alignment.center,
                              child: Column(
                                mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                                children: [
                                  Container(
                                    width:
                                        MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * .8,
                                    height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height *
                                        .07,
                                    child: textField(
                                      'Name',
                                      validatae,
                                      controller: _nameController[i],
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                  SizedBox(
                                    height: 10,
                                  ),
                                  Container(
                                    width:
                                        MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * .8,
                                    height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height *
                                        .07,
                                    child: textField(
                                      'Mobile Number ',
                                      validatae,
                                      controller: _phoneController[i],
                                      isPhoneKeyboard: true,
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                  SizedBox(
                                    height: 5,
                                  ),
                                  Row(
                                    children: [
                                      Container(
                                          height: MediaQuery.of(context)
                                                  .size
                                                  .height *
                                              0.07,
                                          width: MediaQuery.of(context)
                                                  .size
                                                  .width *
                                              0.3,
                                          child: RaisedButton(
                                            onPressed: () {},
                                            color: Colors.white,
                                            focusColor: Colors.grey,
                                            child:
                                                Text('Front ID for tenants '),
                                          )),
                                      SizedBox(
                                        width:
                                            MediaQuery.of(context).size.width *
                                                0.02,
                                      ),
                                      Container(
                                          height: MediaQuery.of(context)
                                                  .size
                                                  .height *
                                              0.07,
                                          width: MediaQuery.of(context)
                                                  .size
                                                  .width *
                                              0.3,
                                          child: RaisedButton(
                                            onPressed: () {},
                                            color: Colors.white,
                                            focusColor: Colors.grey,
                                            child: Text('Rare ID for tenants '),
                                          ))
                                    ],
                                  ),
                                ],
                              ),
                            ),
                          ));
                    } else {
                      return Container(
                        height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.37,
                        width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.92,
                        child: Padding(
                            padding: EdgeInsets.only(
                                left:
                                    MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.015,
                                top: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.08,
                                bottom:
                                    MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.15),
                            child: Material(
                              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(50.0),
                              color: Colors.white,
                              elevation: 4.0,
                              child: Container(
                                alignment: Alignment.center,
                                child: Column(
                                  mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                                  children: [
                                    Container(
                                      width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width *
                                          .8,
                                      height:
                                          MediaQuery.of(context).size.height *
                                              .07,
                                      child: textField(
                                        'Name',
                                        validatae,
                                        controller: _nameController[i],
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                    SizedBox(
                                      height: 10,
                                    ),
                                    Container(
                                      width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width *
                                          .8,
                                      height:
                                          MediaQuery.of(context).size.height *
                                              .07,
                                      
                                      child: textField(
                                        'Mobile Number ',
                                        validatae,
                                        controller: _phoneController[i],
                                        isPhoneKeyboard: true,
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                    SizedBox(
                                      height: 5,
                                    ),
                                    Row(
                                      children: [
                                        Container(
                                            height: MediaQuery.of(context)
                                                    .size
                                                    .height *
                                                0.07,
                                            width: MediaQuery.of(context)
                                                    .size
                                                    .width *
                                                0.3,
                                            child: RaisedButton(
                                              onPressed: () {},
                                              color: Colors.white,
                                              focusColor: Colors.grey,
                                              child:
                                                  Text('Front ID for tenants '),
                                            )),
                                        SizedBox(
                                          width: MediaQuery.of(context)
                                                  .size
                                                  .width *
                                              0.02,
                                        ),
                                        Container(
                                            height: MediaQuery.of(context)
                                                    .size
                                                    .height *
                                                0.07,
                                            width: MediaQuery.of(context)
                                                    .size
                                                    .width *
                                                0.3,
                                            child: RaisedButton(
                                              onPressed: () {},
                                              color: Colors.white,
                                              focusColor: Colors.grey,
                                              child:
                                                  Text('Rare ID for tenants '),
                                            ))
                                      ],
                                    ),
                                  ],
                                ),
                              ),
                            )),
                      );
                    }
                  }))),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: () {
          setState(() {
            count++;
          });
        },
        child: Icon(
          Icons.add,
          size: 30.0,
        ),
      ),
    ));
  }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried wrapping column children with `Expanded` widget?            
https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Expanded-class.html

Comment: no i will try it